# mysql column values in option tag

Tags: java, php, mysql

```
$sql1 = "SELECT c.comm FROM enquiry e JOIN comments c ON e.id = c.enquiryId where e.id = '$memberId' AND e.cmpId = '$companyId'";    
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
echo "<select class='form-control' name='comment'>";
    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        echo "
  <option value='".$row1['comm']."'>".$row1['comm']."</option>

    </select>";
 }
```

I want to echo all the values of c.comm in the option but only one value in getting ptint 
PLease help
[image: As u can see all the values of column are getting print but only one value is inside the option tag, i want all values in the option tag]

Comment: what issue do you have?

Comment: i want in drop down the values of single column in sql

Comment: Move `</select>` out of the `while` loop.

Comment: Also, you'll have to encode html entities before outputting `$row1['comm']`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your closing `</select>` tag after the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write the `select` tags like this:

```
  <select class="form-control" name="comment">
    $sql1 = "SELECT c.comm FROM enquiry e JOIN comments c ON e.id =   c.enquiryId where e.id = '$memberId' AND e.cmpId = '$companyId'";    
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
   while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
     echo "<option value='".$row1['comm']."'>".$row1['comm']."</option>

  }
 </select>
```